# `Spring Data` запрос к сущностям связаним `@manytomany`

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, repository

Добрый день! Есть две сущности, к примеру юзер и документы, связанные многие ко многим. Я хочу выбрать все документы, текущего юзера (через объект не устраивает, т.к. есть доп параметры типа: тип, статус...). Не могу понять, как верно написать запрос. Использую Spring Data.

```
@Query("select c from Doc c , User u where  c.type=:type and u.id = :userId and c.status =:statusId")
List<Edoc> findAllByUserAndType (@Param("type") int type,@Param("userId") long userId ,@Param("statusId") int statusId  );
```

Первая сущность:

```
public class Edoc {
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Edocs_users", schema = "edocs",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "edoc_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}
```

Вторая сущность:

```
public class User {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users" ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Edoc> edocs = new HashSet<Edoc>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Spring Data, JPA репозитории поддерживают создание запросов по именам методов.
Количество параметров при запросе не имеет значение, и запрос можно вообще не писать. В Вашем случае:

```
public interface EdocRepository extends JpaRepository<Edoc, Long> {

    List<Edoc> findAllByUserIdAndTypeAndStatusId(long userId, int type, int statusId);

}
```

Список ключевых слов описан в документации
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation